# Trying to make a simple Array sorter with input numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm very new to C++ or even coding. I was trying to make a simple array sorter, where the I first input the number of elements that will be in the array and then input the elements. My outcome should be the array sorted in ascending order. I have not thought about the case if elements inserted are same. So I would love to get some help from you folks.
The main error that I'm facing is that only the first unsorted element is sorted while the rest are either interchanged or left the same.

```
int main(){
  int x;
  cout<<"Enter no. of elements"<<endl;
  cin>>x;
  int A[x];
  for (int i = 0;i<x;i++){
    cin>>A[i];
  }
  for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
   cout<<A[i]<<",";

  
 
 int count=0;
 
 if(count <= (x-1)){
   for (int i=0;i<(x-1);i++){
      if(A[i]>A[i+1]){
        int a;
        a = A[i];
        A[i] = A[(i+1)];
        A[i+1] = a;
      }
      else if(A[i]<A[i+1]) 
        count++;
    }
  }
 


 cout<<"Sorted array:";
  for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
   cout<<A[i]<<",";

 return 0;


}
```

Comment: This seems like a good opportunity to learn to use a debugger - step through your code and see where it deviates from the expected algorithm. `int A[x];` is not valid C++, use `std::vector`. Also a small example with input, expect and actual output would not hurt. Lastly, your algorithm is `O(n)`, that is suspicious, isn't it? As the best comparison-based sorting cannot be better than `O(n logn)`.

Comment: @Quimby: empirical programming (trials and errors under a debugger) is definitely not the method to advise. First thing, the OP should learn to express in writing what his procedure is deemed to do.

Comment: Although other people suggested how to make good algorithm, I decided to make minimal amount of fixes to make your code working, please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74032750/941531) below.

Answer (score 1):

You declared a variable length array

```
int x;
cout<<"Enter no. of elements"<<endl;
cin>>x;
int A[x];
```

because its size is not a compile-time constant.

However variable length arrays are not a standard C++ feature though some compilers have their own language extensions that support variable length arrays,

It is better to use the class template `std::vector`.

Another problem is that it seems you are trying to use the bubble sort method to sort the array. But this method requires two loops.

Here is a demonstration program that shows how the bubble sort algorithm can be implemented.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for (const auto &item : a)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    for (size_t last = N, sorted = N; not ( last < 2 ); last = sorted)
    {
        for (size_t i = sorted = 1; i < last; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] < a[i - 1])
            {
                //  std::swap( a[i-1], a[i] );
                int tmp = a[i - 1];
                a[i - 1] = a[i];
                a[i] = tmp;
                sorted = i;
            }
        }
    }

    for (const auto &item : a)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be fixed a bit to make it working.

Just replace `if (count <= (x - 1))` with `while (count < (x - 1))` and also set `count = 0;` at start of loop, plus replace `else if (A[i] < A[i + 1])` with just `else`. And your code becomes working!

Necessary fixes I did in code below. Also I did formatting (indents and spaces) to make code looks nicer. Rest remains same.

As I see you have a kind of [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/bG5Px3nY7)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x;
    cout << "Enter no. of elements" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    int A[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        cin >> A[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        cout << A[i] << ",";

    int count = 0;

    while (count < (x - 1)) {
        count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (x - 1); i++) {
            if (A[i] > A[i + 1]) {
                int a;
                a = A[i];
                A[i] = A[(i + 1)];
                A[i + 1] = a;
            } else
                count++;
        }
    }

    cout << "Sorted array:";
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        cout << A[i] << ",";

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
10
7 3 5 9 1 8 6 0 2 4
```

Output:

```
7,3,5,9,1,8,6,0,2,4,Sorted array:0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us try the following method:

- find the largest element in the array and move it to the end, by swapping with the last element;
- repeat with the array but the last element, and so on.

---

To find the largest element in `A[0..m-1]`, scan the array and keep an index to the largest *so far*, let `l`. This index can be initialized to `0`.

```
// Move the largest to the end
int l= 0;
for (int i= 1; i < m; i++)
{
   if (A[i] > A[l]) l= i;
}
// A[l] is the largest in A[0..m-1]
Swap(A[l], A[m-1]);
// A[m-1] is the largest in A[0..m-1]
```

---

To sort, repeat with decreasing `m`. You can stop when the subarray just holds one element:

```
// Sort
for (int m= n-1; m > 1; m--)
{
  // Move the largest to the end
  ....
}
```

---

Writing the `Swap` operation and assembling the whole code is your task. Also check

- correctness of the `Move` for the limit cases `m= 0, 1, 2`.
- correctness of the `Sort` for the limit cases `n= 1, 2, 3`.
- how you could instrument the code to verify that the `Move` does its job.
- how you could instrument the code to verify that the `Sort` does its job.
- what happens in case of equal keys.

Comment: Yep, this is not BubbleSort.

Answer (score -1):

If you are taking the size of array as input from user you have to create your array dynamically in c++ like
int *array=new int(x)
and after taking the inputs of the elements just run a nested loop from 0 to size and
the inner loop from 0 to size-1 and check if(A[i]>A[i+1]) if true then swap the values else continue